# Using defintions to show sin(3x)/3x tends to 1

Tags: real-analysis

The problem allows me to use the definition of sin(x)/x tending to 1 as x tends to 0. Then I want to show $|\frac{sin(3x)}{3x}-1|< \epsilon$

(1) Would it be correct to say take an interval around $c=0$, $0<|3x|<\delta_{1}$
and then $0<|x|<\delta_{1}/3$.

(2) At which point I can take $\delta=\delta_{1}/3$ in the sin(x)/x definition and then I am done?

Is this correct and could someone explain why I can take steps (1) and (2) exactly?

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin$? If you know in advance that $\sin$ is a differentiable function, that is pretty trivial since $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$.

Comment: It specifies to do this solely using the epsilon-delta definition for the limit, so not considering the differentiability of sin(x)

Comment: Yes. However the question here wants me to use the definition (epsilon-delta) of the limit of sin(x)/x as x tends to 0, I am finding some trouble doing this. @user2661923

Comment: My previous comment, which I have deleted, represented a mistake in my thinking.  On further reflection, you can't use composition of functions here, because you are taking the limit as $x \to 0$, and the $~\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} (3x) = 0.$  So, if you tried to use composition of functions, you end up with $~\displaystyle \frac{\sin(3 \times 0)}{3 \times 0}~$ which does not lead you anywhere.  Again, my mistake for suggesting that composition of functions be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Let $\eta>0$ be such that $$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right|<\varepsilon\text{ for }|x|<\eta\hspace{1cm}(*)$$ (the existence of such $\eta$ follows from the convergence $\sin x/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Define $\delta = \eta/3$ and take any $x$ such that $|x|<\delta$. Then $|3x|<3\delta=\eta$, so from (*) we get
$$\left|\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}-1\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: What is the rough work to find that delta=n/3? @Mateo

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. This is obvious if you calculate it a few times. Since you have 3x instead of x, it is three times further away from zero than $x$, so to ensure it is close enough, you have to restrict the position of $x$. In other words: you want |3x| to be smaller than $\eta$, so |x| has to be smaller than $\eta/3$.

Comment: @palt34 You want to choose $\delta$ such that $|x| < \delta$ will imply $|3x| < \eta$.  Since $|3x| = 3 \times |x|$, the computation of $\delta$ is $$3 \times \delta = \eta.$$